# Linux program to look into what you're downloading

Tags: networking, monitoring, internet, download

Is there a linux program that allows you to look into your current download traffic? Something that can list all the addresses I am currently connected to and downloading from.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

check [iftop](http://www.ex-parrot.com/pdw/iftop/) and [nload](http://www.roland-riegel.de/nload/)

> iftop does for network usage what top(1) does for CPU usage. It listens to network traffic on a named interface and displays a table of current bandwidth usage by pairs of hosts. Handy for answering the question "why is our ADSL link so slow?".

---

> nload is a console application which monitors network traffic and bandwidth usage in real time. It visualizes the in- and outgoing traffic using two graphs and provides additional info like total amount of transfered data and min/max network usage.

To peek into the data being downloaded/uploaded: 
[Wireshark](https://www.wireshark.org/)

> Wireshark is the world's foremost network protocol analyzer. It lets you capture and interactively browse the traffic running on a computer network. It is the de facto (and often de jure) standard across many industries and educational institutions.

Comment: thanks, I nload and iftop seem to be what I need (don't want to use wireshark in my use case)

Comment: With top, iftop and nload, information changes rather quickly.  Aside from altering the display update frequency, can you give any tips on how to assimilate this information - especially when you're not in the habit of looking at such things all the time?

Answer (score 3):

Yes, simply run the following command :

```
iftop
```

> iftop does for network usage what top(1) does for CPU usage

[image]

See http://www.ex-parrot.com/~pdw/iftop/